# excel formula to read from a volatile function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a volatile function say `=getprice()` in cell `A1`, that may succeed, returning a price, or fail, returning `#REF!`. Is there a way to write a formula in `B1`, that read from `A1`, if succeed, get the value, and if failed, keep last round value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on Enable iterative calculation with Maximum Iterations set to `1` then:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1),B1,A1)
```

Comment: what does the "maximum change" option mean and how shall i set it? is it that since I only iterate once, the "maximum change" doesn't matter?

Comment: Maximum Iterations, good stuff.  Learn something new today.  Thank you, pnuts.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a late response but here is another alternative that doesn't precisely answer your question, but still, I think it is useful information:

I recently discovered that data-validation drop-down lists are always non-volatile, even if you select a volatile value from the drop-down. The value chosen from the drop-down list will remain in the cell indefinitely until you re-choose from the drop-down again.

In your case, in cell `B1`, you can select data validation and set it up with these settings:

[image]

This way, cell `A1` will constantly be updating, and whenever you want to "capture" this value in `A1`, you just manually select the only available option from the drop-down list in cell `B1`, which will store that value in `B1` indefinitely until you manually select from the drop-down list again.

Again I realize this doesn't precisely answer your question because cell `B1` doesn't automatically update, but this method has two major advantages:

1. It allows Excel to essentially have memory and look at past events (something that could otherwise not be accomplished).
2. It essentially converts a volatile cell to a non-volatile cell.

Converting to a non-volatile cell is in general particularly useful for making your spreadsheet more efficient. For example in cell `A1` you could have the volatile function `= NOW()` and then use this method to snapshot copy this value into cell `B1`, and all cells in your workbook that need `NOW()` in the formula can be based off of cell `B1` instead of `A1`, thus having potential to drastically improve calculation times since `B1` is non-volatile.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, again I realize this answer isn't perfect for this specific application, but having the ability to manually "snapshot" data and keep it non-volatile could be really useful for some applications.

Comment: having temporary memory without using vba is interesting, while more interesting is converting a volatile cell to a non-volatile one. thx sharing!